# Verify that the followings are indeed functors

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

Could anyone check my working please?

---

A functor must fulfill the following criteria.

1. To each $\mathscr C$-object $a$, a $\mathscr D$-object $F(a)$ and
2. To each $\mathscr C$-arrow $f:a\to b$ a $\mathscr D$-arrow $F(f):F(a)\to F(b)$ such that

   - $F(1_a)=1_{F(a)}$ for all $\mathscr C$-objects $a$
   - $F(g\circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)$, whenever $g\circ f$ is defined

---

The identity functor $1_{\mathscr C}:\mathscr C \to \mathscr C$ that has $1_{\mathscr C}(a)=a, 1_{\mathscr C}(f)=f$.

For 1, from left to right: $1_{\mathscr C}(1_a)=1_{\mathscr C}(a)=a=1_{\mathscr C}(a)=1_{1_{\mathscr C}(a)}$. The case for an arbitrary function $f$ is similar.

For 2(a), suppose we have $1_{\mathscr C}(1_a)$. But then $1_a$ just takes us back to $a$, then $1_{\mathscr C}$ by definition maps it to $a$. If we start off with $1_{1_{\mathscr C}(a)}$,$1_{\mathscr C (a)}=a$, and $1_a=a$ too. So regardless of which side we begin with, we still end up with $a$.

Now for 2(b) suppose we have $1_{\mathscr C}(g\circ f)$, but by definition that gives us $g\circ f$. On the other hand if we have $1_{\mathscr C}(g)\circ 1_{\mathscr C}(f)$, since $1_{\mathscr C}(g)=g$ and like wise for $f$, we also end up with $g\circ f$.

---

Power set functor: $\mathscr P: Set \to Set$ maps each set $A$ to its powerset $\mathscr P(A)$, and each function $f:A\to B$ to the function $\mathscr P (f): \mathscr P (A)\to \mathscr P (B)$ from $\mathscr P(A)$ to $\mathscr P(B)$ that assigns to each $X\subseteq A$ its $f$-image $f(X)\subseteq B$.

For 1, if the $\mathscr C$ object is an arbitrary set $A$ in the category $Set$, then the functor $\mathscr P$ by definition assigns $A$ to $\mathscr P(A)$. Likewise if the object is a function $f$, it is also well defined according to the definition of functor as per its definition.

For 2(a), suppose we have $\mathscr P(1_a)$. Since we are working with the category $Set$, $a$ would be a set $A$.$1_A$ would take us back to $A$, so $\mathscr P(1_a)=\mathscr P(A)$. On other hand, if we start from the RHS, $1_{\mathscr P(A)}=\mathscr P(A)$, so both LHS and RHS are identical to the same thing, ie. $\mathscr P(A)$.

For 2(b), suppose we have $\mathscr P(g\circ f)$. Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$. Then $g\circ f: A\to C$, with $\mathscr P(g\circ f):\mathscr P(A) \to \mathscr P(C)$. i.e. $\mathscr P(g\circ f)$ assigns to each $X\subseteq A$ its $g\circ f$ image $g(f(X))\subseteq C$.

On the other hand, $\mathscr P(f): \mathscr P(A)\to \mathscr P(B)$ and $\mathscr P(g):\mathscr P(B)\to \mathscr P(C)$, therefore $\mathscr P(g)\circ \mathscr P(f): \mathscr P(A)\to \mathscr P(C)$.

$\mathscr P(f)$ assigns each $X\subseteq A$ to $f(X)\subseteq B$, and $\mathscr P(g)$ assigns each $Y\subseteq B$ to $g(Y)\subseteq C$. But because $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$, if we take $f(X)=Y$, then $\mathscr P(g)\circ\mathscr P(f)$ assigns each $X\subseteq A$ to $g(f(X))\subseteq C$. Therefore given an arbitrary $X\subseteq A$ both $\mathscr P(g\circ f)$ and $\mathscr P(g)\circ\mathscr P(f)$ would output the same thing, i.e. $g(f(X))\subseteq C$.

Comment: You should clean up 2(a): we need $1_{\mathcal P(A)}=\mathcal P(1_A)$. Also, why does the equation in 2(b) hold? Can you spell it out?

Comment: @Berci For 2(a), I edited it so that LHS and RHS are identical to $\mathscr P(A)$, is that ok? For 2(b), which equation are you referring to?

Comment: No, $P(A)$ is a set and $1_{P(A)}$ is a function, these are not the same thing. For b), I refer to the only equation you should prove: $P(g\circ f)=P(g)\circ P(f)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 2.a) it's about the $\mathscr P$-image of the *identity function* being itself an identity function. 
By definition, we have $\mathscr P(1_A)(X)=1_A(X)=X$ for every $X\in \mathscr P(A)$, so it's indeed the identity function.

For 2.b) you should prove $\mathscr P(g\circ f) =\mathscr P(g)\circ \mathscr P(f)$, using again the definition of $\mathscr P$ on arrows.

Comment: Thank you; I've edited my solution to 2(b), would you mind taking another look please? I've tried to be as explicit as possible so if this fails I don't know what I can do anymore...

Comment: Also, while I understand what you said about 2(a), but if we can prove x and y are identical to z (in this case $\mathscr P(A)$), wouldn't that also prove that x and y are identical?

Comment: Yes, it is much better now. For your second question, what are $x, y, z$?

Comment: Thank you so much! $x, y, z$ would be $\mathscr P(1_a), 1_{\mathscr P(A)}, \mathscr P(A)$ respectively, the proof would be my failed attempt above

Comment: No, $P(1_A)=1_{P(A)}$ is a *function* while $P(A)$ is a *set*, they are not identical.